# How can I detect SQL injection vulnerability with Python script

Tags: python, sql-injection

Right now I use this code:

```
...    
def is_vulnerable(response):
        """A simple boolean function that determines whether a page 
        is SQL Injection vulnerable from its `response`"""
        errors = {
            "you have an error in your sql syntax;",
            "warning: mysql",
            "unclosed quotation mark after the character string",
            "quoted string not properly terminated",
        }
        for error in errors:
            if error in response.content.decode().lower():
                return True
        return False    
    
    def scan_sql_injection(url):
            for c in "\"'":
                new_url = f"{url}{c}"
                print("[!] Trying", new_url)
                res = s.get(new_url)
                if is_vulnerable(res):
                    print("[+] SQL Injection vulnerability detected, link:", new_url)
                    return
        forms = get_all_forms(url)
        print(f"[+] Detected {len(forms)} forms on {url}.")
...
```

Which is found at https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/sql-injection-vulnerability-detector-in-python. I scanned a simple website which is vulnerable to SQL injection, but the output of the detector script is only "Detected 1 forms on URL". It looks like the detector only tests the URL for SQL Injection.

I think I need to write a new FOR loop that tests the input fields. Can someone help me out?

Comment: use requests/urllib3 to get html text, use bs4 to loop through the data and check for strings that might include vulnerabilities